# Dompf load forever laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-4, dompdf

Im using **dompf** trying to generate a **pdf** and save it to the storage folder and a database, the problem is when i try to generate the **pdf**, it never load, when i use the sample code in **github** it work, it shows "test", but when i try to load a view it takes forever. this is the code i'm using

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.myView',$myData);
return $pdf->stream();
```

I have tried using the `download` and the `save` methods, but doens't work and the page load forever but the pdf is never generated.

and the view just show 4 or 6 elements with 1 main call `$hist`, returning the view is rendered without problems.

```
<style type="text/css">
      Bunch of css.
</style>

<table class="center-block">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/boletin/btn_cabeza.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4" class="aside">
            <a href="{{ URL::to('contacto/donaciones') }}">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/boletin/btn_dona.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive center-block" >
            </a>

            <div class="social-container">
                <h3>Siguenos en:</h3>
                <hr>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/fundaepekeina"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://fundaepekeina.org"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/funda.epekeina"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/fundaepekeina"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h2 class="text-blue">Historias Epékeinas</h2>
            <br>
            @if(count($hist->imagenes) > 0)
              <img src="{{ asset('images/news/'.$hist->imagenes->first()->image) }}" class="img-responsive img-boletin" alt="{{ $hist->titles->first()->text }}">
            @endif
            <div class="bg-green padding-20">
                <h2 class="boletin-title">
                  {{ $hist->titles->first()->text }}
                  @if(!is_null($hist->subtitle))
                    {{ $hist->subtitle->titles->first()->text }}
                  @endif
                </h2>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="text-justify">
                {{ substr(strip_tags($hist->descriptions->first()->text), 0, 1600) }}[...]
                <br>
                <a href="{{ URL::to('quienes-somos/historias-epekeinas/'.$hist->slugs->first()->text) }}" class="pull-right">Leer más</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $k = 0;?>
    @foreach($article as $a)
        @if($k == 0 || $k%2 == 0)
            <tr>
        @endif
        @if(!empty($principal))
            @if($a->slugs->first()->text != $principal->id)
                <td class="news fixedHeight bg-{{ $colors[$j] }}">

                    @if(count($a->imagenes) > 0)
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/news/'.$a->imagenes->first()->image) }}" class="img-responsive center-block img-boletin" alt="{{ $a->titles->first()->text }}">
                    @else
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" class="img-responsive center-block img-boletin" alt="{{ $a->titles->first()->text }}">
                    @endif
                    <h2 class="boletin-title">{{ $a->titles->first()->text }}</h2>
                    <p class="text-justify">{{ substr(strip_tags($a->descriptions->first()->text), 0, 300) }} [...]</p>
                    <a target="_blank" href="{{ URL::to('noticias/'.$a->slugs->first()->text) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">Leer más</a>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </td>
              <?php $k++; ?>
            @endif
        @else
            <td class="news fixedHeight bg-{{ $colors[$j] }}">
                @if(count($a->imagenes) > 0)
                    <img src="{{ asset('images/news/'.$a->imagenes->first()->image) }}" class="img-responsive center-block img-boletin" alt="{{ $a->titles->first()->text }}">
                @else
                    <img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" class="img-responsive center-block img-boletin" alt="{{ $a->titles->first()->text }}">
                @endif
                <h2 class="boletin-title">{{ $a->titles->first()->text }}</h2>
                <p class="text-justify">{{ substr(strip_tags($a->descriptions->first()->text), 0, 300) }} [...]</p>
                <a target="_blank" href="{{ URL::to('noticias/'.$a->slugs->first()->text) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">Leer más</a>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </td>
            <?php $k++; ?>
        @endif
        <?php $j++; ?>
          @if($j == 4)
          <?php $j=0; ?>
          @endif

        @if(($k != 0 && $k%2 == 0) || $k == count($article))
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="text-center">
            <h3>&copy; Derechos Reservados Funda Epékeina 2016.</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="container center-block">
        <div class="bg-square bg-blue"></div>
        <div class="bg-square bg-yellow"></div>
        <div class="bg-square bg-green"></div>
        <div class="bg-square bg-pink"></div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

what could be wrong? is there any other choice for generating pdf.

Comment: you should set your debug mode on and check laravel.log file for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check those points in order:

- For Laravel 4.* I suggest you to use this DOMPDF wrapper https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4
- Maybe your view is trying to render content out of the page, try to add dinamic page break, you can do so by styling an element with page-break-before: always; or page-break-after: always.; Try to delete the foreach and adding 1 or 2 static  element rendering it in one page
- Check for errors in the view by rendering it in html with `return View::make('emails.myView',$myData)->render();`. 
  Check php and html sintax, dompdf doesn't work if some html tags are
  not well closed
- Consider to use Knp-snappy library for Laravel https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/tree/0.1